# Every so often AWS target-groups become unhealthy and ornery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-alb

Every so often, I find that a service deployment refuses to complete because target-groups get into an unhealthy state even though the port-assignments are fine and the tasks appear to be fine. Every deployment and redeployment, even of earlier versions, will just start failing (the tasks come up, and then are stopped with no error output in the task or ECS console).

Once I identify this behavior, I need to blow away our target-group (and ALB, as a necessary preliminary step), sometimes in the middle of the day, and have Terraform redeploy them both. It last happened a couple of months ago and I lost some time reverse-engineering every facet of the process until I happened to learn this. It just happened again today.

Is this just an accepted behavior of the system, or is there something that I should look into that might be inducing this? I can't imagine very large customers (with hundreds of services and zero room for issues like this that could multiple proportionally) have to deal with this.